# Travel the world and Travel around the world

Tags: phrases

- travel the world
- travel around the world

Is there any difference between the two phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Travel around the world" is often used in a fairly literal sense of proceeding more-or-less entirely in a single direction in order to proceed around the globe in a giant circle.

"Travel the world" is used to speak going to a relatively large number of varied international destinations.  Someone who has made seven trips to Paris would not be considered to have "travelled the world", but someone who has made one trip each to Paris, Rome, Moscow, Perth, Cairo, Singapore, and Mumbai would have a much better claim to it.